# Compose pictures lined up on the page

Tags: blogger

> I want to know how to compose pictures lined up 3 to 5 horizontally on the page?
> I have tried a way to shrink the pixel size of the image, but the result remains the same. So, what kind of HTML format should I use, and how to use the code?
>
> This is an example of a link arrangement of pictures on my website, which is only arranged vertically!
> http://www.kubahmasjid123.com/p/gambar-kubahb.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Blogger, you are either going to have to select a template with a wider content area or make thumbnails of your images.

Think of it this way.  You have a page where the content area is 680px wide.  If you want 3 pictures across the page they are each going to have to be around 200px wide i.e. 3 x 200 = 600

At the moment most of your images are 320px wide.  But they don't even go 2 across because of the styles in the template.  It might be designed that they are one above the other.  Maybe it is the way you are inserting them in the post.  Who knows...

To give a detailed fix is a bit too complex for this forum, but now you get the gist of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite as simple as just picking a wider template:  it looks like you have put the pictures into your post with the post-editor, which by default puts pictures one under another, or has options to flow text around them (left of right).   It doesn't have simple options for displaying pictures side by side, even if they are small enough to fit.

But it is possible to do this, by choosing a small picture size (from the hover menu in the post-editor) and also by going in to HTML mode and putting each picture inside a DIV statement which has a style applied to it like this:

> style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 2em; margin-right:
>   2em; width: NN;"

I've described this in a lot more detail here:   http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/how-to-put-pictures-side-by--side-using-html.html